# Is it ok to say, "by 2020 I would be the most famous teacher in town"?

Tags: grammar

> by 2020 I would be the most famous teacher in town

I know that will, not would, is the right word for this sentence, but does that make "would" incorrect? Or is it also possible but with a different meaning?

Answer (score 6):

Since it's 2017, using "would" implies a *conditional*, so you need some kind of "if" statement

> By 2020 I **would be** the most famous teacher in town **if** I can find some students.

Otherwise you should use "will" or, if some other relatively uncertain verb like *hope*, *intend*, *aspire*, *plan*, etc.

However, you can use *would* to refer to past events *that are in the future* relative to some other past event, for example if you were writing your memoirs:

> By 1995 I **would be** a wealthy artist, but in 1990 I was still struggling to pay for paint.

(Edit) As Mv Log mentions in the comments below, you can also use "would" when backshifting indirect quotes:

> He told me, "By 2020 I will be the most famous teacher in this town."
>   ⇩
>   He told me that by 2020 he **would be** the most famous teacher in this town."

Comment: Also, let's not forget indirect speech: _I hope you do remember what I told you yesterday—that by 2020 I would_ (will is also possible) _be the most famous teacher in town._